# How long do I need to wait to get a treadmill?

Tags: probability

There are $15$ treadmills at my gym each person uses them for $40$ minutes. The possible times spent on the treadmill, for example $5$ minutes or $20.23$ minutes, are equally likely. I arrive at my gym, I see every treadmill is occupied.

What is the probability that at least one person gets off within $10$ minutes of my arrival?

This is a practical question so I'm asking it here. My assumption is it's $1$ minus the complement to the $15$th power.

Comment: Your idea makes sense. Did you try that approach? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't completely clear to me but I think you mean the possible time someone spends on a treadmill is a uniform distribution from 0 to 40 mins.

In that case, first imagine there's one treadmill. Let's say when you walk into the gym, the person on that treadmill will have a total time x spent on it. Let's find the expected value of x. Let's say the gym is open for y minutes a day and take the limit $y\rightarrow \infty$, then the probability that you walk in on a particular treadmill user, User 1, given that they use it for X minutes is $p(\textrm{walk in on User 1}|x=X)=X/y$. The average time to use a treadmill is 20 mins, so the total number of treadmill users is $y/20$, so $p(x=X|\textrm{walk in on User 1})=\frac{p(\textrm{walk in on User 1}|x=X)p(x=X)}{p(\textrm{walk in on User 1})}=\frac{(X/y)(1/40)}{20/y}=X/800$.

The probability that they'll finish within 10 mins given x is $p(\textrm{finish in 10 mins}|x)=10/x$.

The expected probability of them finishing in 10 mins is:

$\int_{0}^{40} p(\textrm{finish in 10 mins}|x=X)p(x=X|\textrm{walk in on User 1})dX=\int_{0}^{40} 10/800 dX=0.5$.

if there are 15 treadmills and they are all independent, the total probability that at least one person gets off within 10 mins is $1-(1-0.5)^{15}$.

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean that each person spends exactly 40 minutes on the treadmill, and the distribution of how much time each person has completed by the time you arrive ("time spent on the treadmill") is uniformly distributed between 0 and 40 minutes. So the chance of any one person being in the last 10 minutes of their 40-minute workout would be be 10/40=0.25.